# The area of greatest circle included in a right trapezoid

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, quadrilateral

A trapezium ABCD for which AD //BC and AD = 18 cm , BC = 33 cm , CD = 25 cm and angle ABC = 90 degree . Whats the area of the greatest circle which can be drawn inside the trapezium ?
My turn :
The greatest circle is that touches the side of the rectangle ABED where DE is perpendicular to BC meets it at E and AE = AB = CE = $\sqrt{CD^2 - CE^2 }=\sqrt{ 25^2 - 15^2 }= 20 $cm 
Then compute the radius and calculating the area of the circle. Is the solution correct ?
Note : Calculus is not allowed

Comment: Please draw a figure.

Comment: The radius seems to be 10.

Comment: The rectangle $ABED$ has the sides $18$ and $20,$ what you did not want I think.

Comment: You should at once use the term "right trapezoid".

Answer (score 1):

The trapezium is part of a right triangle $BCF,$ see figure. In similar triangles $\triangle FAD$ and $\triangle FBC$ 
$$\frac{18}{33}=\frac{d}{d+25},$$ 
hence $d=30.$ Thus $\triangle FBC$ is Pythagorean with the lengths of sides $$FC=55, FB=44, BC=33.$$ In the similar triangle $\triangle FAD$ are the sides $30, 24, 18.$ Therefore, $AB=44-24=20.$

As shows the figure, the largest circle has diameter $AB.$

[image]

Comment: you meant: "In the similar triangle $\Delta A\color{red}{DF}$ are..."

Comment: how do you know the circle does not cross the right side of trapezoid? Well, the side $AB$ you could easily find by dropping altitude from $D$ to the side $BC$ and using Pythagorean: $AB=\sqrt{CD^2-CG^2}=\sqrt{25^2-(33-18)^2}=20$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my typo @farruhota. As for your second comment, I left space to OP to complete the argumentation.

Answer (score 0):

Now, you need to show that if we'll take a circle with a radius is greater than $10$,

so we can not place this circle inside the trapezoid.

Can you end it now?

The hint:

Let $\Phi$ be a circle with radius is greater than $10$, $O$ be a center of the circle and $\Phi$ is placed inside the trapezoid.

Now, take an altitude of the trapezoid such that $O$ is placed on this altitude.